# set prompts for bash Osx?

Tags: macos, bash

i am trying to set up a prompt in terminal as a safety net to ask me yes or no when I want to
`-cp`, `-rm`, `-mv` etc. I created a `~/.bashrc` file but my syntax inside the folder is wrong i believe because i do not get a prompt when i execute one of the following commands. Can anyone tell me the proper syntax for doing this in bash? Here is what i have in my `~/.bashrc` now

```
alias rm ‘rm -i’
alias mv ‘mv -i’
alias cp ‘cp -i’
```

This works on .tcshrc but apparently not in bash, any help is appreciated.

Comment: `-i` only prompts if the destination exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax in bash is `alias name=value`.

For example:

```
alias rm='rm -i'
alias mv='mv -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
```

Check the `man` page for more information.